# Why size of frame is empty in navigationBar?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I try to get frame from navigationBar and get zero width and height of size. Code:

```
CGRect f = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
```

In debug mode I get zero from f.height.

What is wrong?

Comment: have you double check that `self.navigationController.navigationBar` is not `nil` ?

Comment: navigationBar is not nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
NSLog(@"frame:%@",NSStringFromCGRect(f));
```

This will show frame.

Answer (score 0):

in your code : `f.height`  should be `f.size.height`

---

By doing so : this code

```
CGRect f = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
NSLog(@"f.size = (%.2f, %.2f)", f.size.width, f.size.height);
```

is giving me this output :

> 2012-01-14 15:54:32.909 naveCon[4071:207] f.size = (320.00, 44.00)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are logging int as float or float as int. If you do

```
int ih = f.size.height;
```

or

```
float fh = f.size.height;
```

you will not see any warning as float will be converted to float, but trying to log

```
NSLog("%d", fh);
```

or

```
NSLog("%f", ih);
```

should give you a warning, just read it.